# is it not able to delete Child node directly?

Tags: removechild

I am a very beginner and code is like this:

```
    function itemDone(e) {
      var target, elParent, elGrandparent;
      target = getTarget(e);
      elParent = target.parentNode;
      elGrandparent = target.parentNode.parentNode;
      elGrandparent.removeChild(elParent);
```

is there any other way that I can delete the child element directly with any keyword rather than find parent and grandparent and then delete child element from parent. 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. You need to know the parent in order to remove the child. Unless you are dealing with double indirection which you would need pointers for and a different language.